# VSCode - Disable font ligatures in find and replace boxes

Tags: visual-studio-code, fonts, ligature

I want to disable font ligatures in the find and replace text boxes. For example, if I want to search for `</` (HTML closing tags pattern) it changes it to downward arrow ligature:

[image]

I already have `"editor.fontLigatures": false,` set in my `settings.json` but this doesn't seem to be affecting the search box. Same behaviour is visible in the Global Search menu.

Search still does work but I don't want to see the ligature. How can I disable this ?

Thanks!